# mediaPlayer not runnig with sdcard file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Please help me

my mediaPalyer did not run the file from sd card,

where is my fault in the code below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);
    play=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(getActivity(),Uri.parse("/sdcard/qesa1_1.ogg"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}});

    return view;}}
```

Comment: Hard-coding "/sdcard" in the path isn't really recommended. It will be different on different devices. Are you sure that is the correct path?

Comment: Ya im sure.is there any wrong code?

Answer (score 0):

i found my mistake
its with run time permission of read_external_storage